# Check if next Task is an End Event using apache activiti

Tags: java, spring, activiti

I am wondering how I could check if the next task is an End Event. In my code I check the next task Name to see if the process is done.
Could you please provide me with activiti best practices to modelize BPM proccess ?

Best regards.

```java
if(nextTask.getName().startWith("Done"){
// process done...
}
```

Comment: why not use task listener at the before the end task? the event START/COMPLETE might help you

Comment: I will try it and go back to you :) thank you !

Answer (score 1):

For executing your custom logic before a specific task or event. you should use [TaskListeners](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#taskListeners)/[ExecutionListeners](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#executionListeners).

This way your code will be reusable across all your process definitions and the the hook points (for listeners) allows you to manage your code execution on different types of events.